# Cpanel Htaccess force URL

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cpanel

I need help with .htaccess

click this below URL you ll see port and IP in URL

[123chatgroups.info (url is with port and IP)](http://123chatgroups.info/client/123flashchat.swf?init_host=208.98.56.230&init_port=55527)

i want only this

[URL without port and ip](http://123chatgroups.info/client/)

i want url without IP and Port

what to put in .htaccess

regards

Comment: I think your flash .swf file is looking at the ip and port. I don't think any .htaccess rewrite is going to help with that. You probably have to hardcore those values into your .swf file.

Comment: http://www.123flashchat.com/docs/v90/Chat-Client-Parameters you don't need htaccess for that, see the javascript parameter options and stop using it with the parameter on URL.

Comment: @prix  How to hide it ? can you please be more precise :)

Comment: @RicardoDosSantos Read the above link it contains an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think the below example will work, but if your still passing variables via a GET string though embed code It will redirect that request as well.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/client/123flashchat\.swf$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)init_host=(.*)($|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)init_port=(.*)($|&)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /client/ [R=302,L]
```

Comment: @RicardoDosSantos I have updated the code, but can you give me more insight then that its not working, are you getting an error, try removing differnt lines and see if it works ect.

Comment: @ prix
@ chris
i guess editing needs to be done in this file ? 
http://pastebin.com/dDbELf2F

Answer (score -1):

you can simply hide ports and hosts in 123flashchat.swf by open this file with

http://www.free-decompiler.com/flash/download/

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/xkjzy.png]

for example you can see my chats https://12allchat.io/chat/

http://chat.domo3warda.com/123flashchat.swf
here im hiding the ports